# Hide with jquery a specific HTML pattern where it repeats on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

My regex & jquery skills are failing me.

I need to hide ALL of the following html where it appears on a page (the following is spat out by a database):

```
<p><strong>External Links for:</strong></p>  
<p></p>
```

I'd be very grateful for a jsfiddle (or similar) that uses jquery to hide only exactly ALL of the above. (Note: Sometimes there will be data inside the second paragraph. If so, this should remain untouched).

Thanks in advance!

*For the record, I have tried to do this myself but my jquery skills are rubbish so best to start with a blank slate as I expect it will only take a few lines of code to implement.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to return ONLY instances of BOTH paragraphs in a row, you can create a complex filter like so:

```
$('p').filter(function(i,el) {
    var test1 = $(el).html() == "<strong>External Links for:</strong>";
    var test2 = $(el).next('p').html() == "";
    return test1 && test2;
}).next().addBack().hide(); // or .remove()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/d7fz4/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over and check if text is `External Links for:` then hide it or remove it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p > strong").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == "External Links for:") {
            //$(this).hide();
            $(this).closest('p').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/D9cE4/2/)

### OR

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p > strong").each(function () {
        return $(this).text() === "External Links for:";
    }).closest('p').remove();
});
```

[**Alternate Way DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/D9cE4/8/)

Note: Wrap your code in [document-ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Might want to do `p > strong` in case they want to keep nested `strong` tags with that text that are nested down in a `p` tag.

Comment: @Satpal
I've just implemented the alternate way, but now the contents of the first para are removed also - in my page anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
$( function() {
    $( 'p>strong' ).each( function() {
        $( this ).next( 'p' ).remove();
        $( this ).remove();
    });
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VzwyA/)